# How to fix 'Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused' when I start rq-worker?

Tags: python, linux, flask, redis, worker

I'm working with flask, redis and rq-worker in my web application that is hosted ina debian 9 machine. When I start rq-worker I get this error: "Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused".

I already checked if Redis was installed and running, I tried these comands:

```sh
/opt/apps/mywebapp/flask$ ps aux | grep redis
sib       4987  0.0  0.0  12784   976 pts/2    S+   09:37   0:00 grep redis
redis     6574  0.1  0.0  40860  3512 ?        Ssl  may28   3:38 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

```sh
/opt/apps/mywebapp/flask$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

I've read other post and this is an evidence that Redis is running and woking.

I also check the file redis.conf and I set this variable:

```sh
bind 127.0.0.1
```

I tried again.

```sh
/opt/apps/mywebapp/flask$ rq worker
```

But I keep receiving the error.

```
Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

Comment: Can you provide your app config for redis connection? It may have something to do with credentials you provided.

Comment: Hello, I got help from a friend, in fact it was the redis configuration bind property, I was set like 127.0.0.1 ::00 but the correct configuration was  127.0.0.1 ::01. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, It was the redis configuration bind property, I set it 127.0.0.1 ::00 but the correct configuration was 127.0.0.1 ::01.

Answer (score 0):

you must put your Ip by ipconfig instead of localhost